# Windows 8.1 - Windows Installer Error?

Tags: windows-8.1, microsoft-office-2013

Quite some time ago (around five years) I began modding a game called Homeworld 2. I've used many tools since then and the main one I use is used to extract files from the game's data archive (I don't know the specifics of the format, but I know it's not a normal everyday archive format like ZIP, RAR, or 7Z). It's called HW2ICArchive, is coded in Visual Basic (I don't know what version), and I've been using it without errors since the first use.

Recently, actually yesterday, I installed Microsoft Office (just Word and PowerPoint) 2013. Today, I opened up HW2ICArchive and it gave me an error: H80004023. Upon researching, apparently this is caused either by Visual Basic libraries or missing or invalid registry key entries. On Microsoft's support site, they have a couple question threads with answers that involve Office 2013, but none of them specify any registry keys that I have on my computer right now. I have a few similarly-designated ones, but the number arrangement doesn't match the one on the thread.

The error popup window that comes up when I try to launch it also states what others said it shows on their computers': "a Microsoft software installer error has occurred".

I was thinking about deleting all temporary file directories in C:\Windows\Installer, but according to Microsoft, those temporary files are "important" and should not be modified or deleted. I'm still looking for a surefire solution to this occurrence. Anyone have a similar problem and have managed to solve it?

Answer (score -1):

Solved. Simply uninstalled .NET Forms for Applications via the included Office 2013 installer package.